# Uncaught TypeError: table.createElement is not a function

Tags: javascript, table

Пытаюсь добавить элементы в таблицу, написал следующую функцию:

```
function Table(x,y,answer) {
        let table = document.getElementById("MyTable");
        let row = table.createElement("TR");
        table.appendChild(row);
        let td1 = table.createElement("TD");
        let td2 = table.createElement("TD");
        row.appendChild(td1);
        row.appendChild(td2);
        td1.innerHTML = x;
        td2.innerHTML = y;

}
```

Ошибка вылетает на

```
let row = table.createElement("TR");
```

Вот html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lab_1</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <script src="js/Handler.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Draw.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Request.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Table.js"></script>

    <div id="table">
        <table id="MyTable">

        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="information" onsubmit="return false;">
        <form>
            <p><b>Введите X:</b><br>
                <input id="inputX" type="text" name="TextField">
            <p><b>Введите Y:</b><br>
                <input id="inputY" type="text" name="TextField">
            <p><b>Введите R:</b><br>
                <input id="inputR" type="text" name="TextField" value=3 onchange=DrawFigure()>
                <input id="button" type="submit" name="Button" onclick={CheckInput()}>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="picture">
        <canvas id="canvas" width=280 height=280></canvas>
        <script>
            {
                DrawFigure()
            }
        </script>
    </div>

</div>

<kbd>
</kbd>
</body>
</html>
```

Сама функция вызывается из CheckInput(), с ней все хорошо.
Может кто-то подсказать в чем проблема?

Comment: с чего ты взял, что у table должна быть эта функция?

Comment: o_o `document.createElement`

Comment: @Grundy, справедливо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вы можете [видеть по списку методов](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element#Methods), у элементов нет метода `.createElement()`, он есть [только у документа](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).